# VBScript to copy files from documents library from Android device in my network to Windows directory

Tags: android, windows, vbscript, file-sharing

I have .xlsx files in the documents folder of multiple Androids tablet devices on my network.  The directories are named the same.  Therefore the only difference between the directories is the devices name itself.
e.g. 
\device1\documents*
\device2\documents*
etc.

I know the names of the devices on the network, and so I am trying to MOVE using VBSCRIPT all the files from the \documents* directory to a central directory on a computer in the same network, e.g. "\computer\desktop\devicedocumentfolder\"

This is what I have so far.  Conceptually, I am missing something with the process of identifying the file(s) in each device directory and moving them all to the main computer where I am running this script from.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Dim oFSO, sDList, sDevice
Dim file
Const ForReading = 1

'Get devices-------------------

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sDList = oFSO.OpenTextFile("c:[computername]\desktop\devicenames.txt")
Do Until sDList.AtEndOfStream
sDevice = sDList.ReadLine
msgbox(sDevice)

'Get and move files from each device to main computer -------
mainComp = "\\c:[computername]\desktop\deviceDocuments\"
file = "\\" & sDevice & "\documents\*"
If oFSO.FileExists(file) Then
msgbox("file exists")
oFSO.movefile file, mainComp
else
msgbox("no files exist on this device")
end if

Loop
sdList.Close
WScript.Echo "Finished moving files from devices"
```

Comment: Sorry all, I should have said "move" in the title and ".csv" instead of ".xlsx".

Comment: This is assuming that your Android devices expose CIFS / Samba-like file shares. I'm reasonably sure they won't, and I don't know if it's possible to set that up. (Or does \\sDevice\documents work for you?)  I suspect you'll need another mechanism to get the files off the devices, particularly if you want to do it remotely.

Comment: @Rup great point!  I wasn't even thinking about that.  If I decide to use a Linux workstation to connect, I "believe" it would make it easier?  It now seems that I will need a third party app installed in order to creates a FTP server on the android device.  Is this really the only way?

Comment: The `mainComp` variable doesn’t contain a valid UNC path.

Comment: @data1 if the question is incorrect you can [edit] it instead of adding corrections in the comments.